# Install and Configure elasticsearch on hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch

I want to use elasticsearch on hadoop. Can any one suggest me step by step installation and configuration of elasticsearch on hadoop? Is there version dependency of elasticsearch and hadoop?

Comment: Read this document  http://hortonworks.com/blog/configure-elastic-search-hadoop-hdp-2-0/

Comment: Can you at least show some search efforts?

Answer (score 2):

Installation:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/install.html

Configuration:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html

> Hadoop 1.x (ideally the latest stable version in the 1.x line,
>   currently 1.2.1) or 2.x (ideally the latest stable version, currently
>   2.2.0). elasticsearch-hadoop is tested daily against Apache Hadoop.  Any distro compatible with Apache Hadoop should work just fine.