# Install and configure elasticsearch on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I've already read through this pages and other related links to install and configure elasticsearch on hadoop. 
[Install and Configure elasticsearch on hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942496/install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-hadoop)

But, I didn't still have some questions.

I'm using an elasticsearch and spark/hadoop separately; in specific, I'm using cloudera hadoop and elasticsearch is running on other linux boxes.
In hadoop, I have one edge node to submit a spark job and the job is running on other 6 nodes through executors with config.

1. This installation guide below is not much informative for me.

(1) Elasticsearch keeps indices on HDFS when I install elasticsearch-hadoop binary on each node? 
(2) If so, where do I need to put jar binary?
elasticsearch-spark_2.11-2.2.0.jar
elasticsearch-hadoop-2.2.0.jar

Actually, with elasticsearch-hadoop-2.2.0.jar, I can read/write documents from/to elasticsearch which is running on linux machines.

```
sc.makeRDD(docs).saveToEs(indexname + "/" + typename, Map( "es.nodes" -> ES_HOSTN_ODE_ADDRESS, "es.port" -> ES_HOST_PORT))
```

(3) how do I need to set data path for hdfs? 
currently elasticsearch has been configured like

```
path.data: /data1,/data2,/data3,/data4
```

(4) are there some other good documents/pages to refer ?

```
elasticsearch-hadoop binaries can be obtained either by downloading them from the elastic.co site as a ZIP (containing project jars, sources and documentation) or by using any Maven-compatible tool with the following dependency:


<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

jar above contains all the features of elasticsearch-hadoop and does not require any other dependencies at runtime; in other words it can be used as is.        elasticsearch-hadoop binary is suitable for both Hadoop 1.x and Hadoop 2.x (also known as YARN) environments without any changes.
```

2. Using scala on spark, I can query documents from elasticsearch, but the queried data is not parallelized for each executor. 
   If I use elasticsearch-hadoop and query data from hdfs, the data is automatically parallelized (RDD) like parquet files without having to

   sc.parallelize(*data*);
3. For me, pushing/pulling big data are important with visualization using several tools such as Kibana. 
   Are there any strong advantages elasticsearch-hadoop against elasticsearch?

Answer (score 4):

From Elasticsearch's [website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/reference.html)

> Elasticsearch for Apache Hadoop is an open-source, stand-alone, self-contained, small library that allows Hadoop jobs (whether using Map/Reduce or libraries built upon it such as Hive, Pig or Cascading or new upcoming libraries like Apache Spark ) to interact with Elasticsearch. One can think of it as a connector that allows data to flow bi-directionaly so that applications can leverage transparently the Elasticsearch engine capabilities to significantly enrich their capabilities and increase the performance.

So as per my understanding answer to your questons:

> (1) Elasticsearch keeps indices on HDFS when I install elasticsearch-hadoop binary on each node?

No, Elasticsearch-Hadoop is a library by which a Hadoop Job can load or store data to/from Elasticsearch.

> (2) If so, where do I need to put jar binary? elasticsearch-spark_2.11-2.2.0.jar elasticsearch-hadoop-2.2.0.jar

These libraries must be present in the classpath of Spark:[Add exteranl jars to classpath](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) or Hadoop:[Add exteranl jars to classpath](https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/hadoop-add-third-party-libraries-to-mapreduce-job/) job .

> (3) how do I need to set data path for hdfs?

I don't think so that this step is required to access elasticsearch data in Hadoop/Spark Job.

> (4) are there some other good documents/pages to refer ?

I refered [Elasticsearch Apache Spark : native support](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html)  for my purpose.

> 2. Using scala on spark, I can query documents from elasticsearch, but the queried data is not parallelized for each executor. If I use elasticsearch-hadoop and query data from hdfs, the data is automatically parallelized (RDD) like parquet files without having to
>      sc.parallelize(data);

Yes your are right. The adavantages of using Elasticsearch-Hadoop & Elasticsearch-spark over Elasticsearch Java/Scala Client are same as inherent advantages of using Hadoop or Spark i.e. distribute the processing load over the cluster.

> 3. For me, pushing/pulling big data are important with visualization using several tools such as Kibana. Are there any strong advantages elasticsearch-hadoop against elasticsearch?

As already mentioned 'elasticsearch-hadoop' is just a library.

Comment: Nice answer. Is not possible elasticsearch use hadoop to get the information without caching it? I want to use kibana to show my hadoop information using elasticsearch as a transparent "data proxy"